# Как вывести текущий цвет страницы в alert?

Tags: css, background, alert

Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Хочу вывести цвет текущей страницы в alert. Нижеследующий код ничего не выводит. Если использовать только background, то будет полная информация о фоне страницы, мне это не подходит. Если использовать background-color, то alert ничего не выдает. Как решить вопрос?

```
function knowColor() {
                let page_color = '';
                page_color = document.body.style.background-color;
                alert("Поточний колір сторінки: " + page_color);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы просто неправильно вводите background-color, в JS а конкретней в объекте `style` он должен записываться вот так: `backgroundColor`, то есть в итоге код должен быть вот такой:

```js
function knowColor() {
    let page_color = document.body.style.backgroundColor
    alert("Поточний колір сторінки: " + page_color)
}
```

И да, не нужно указывать пустую строку чтобы потом назначить на ваш variable какую-то другую строку. Также можно узнать цвет заднего фона `<body>` вот так: `document.body.style['backgroundColor']`

Comment: так тоже можно `document.body.style['background-color']`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 0):

"Обращения" к свойствам которые разделяются дефисом, обычно заменяется на [camelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), т.е.
`background-color` => `.style.backgroundColor`,
`mix-blend-mode` =>? `.style.mixBlendMode` и т.д.

Либо обращайтесь к свойству через квадратные скобки `.style['background-image']`

---

А вообще, вы не получите таким образом цвет, если он не задан до этого через тот же `.style.backgroundColor` ранее, т.к. через `.style` можно получить только [инлайновые стили](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/style).
Чтобы получить стили CSS, лучше использовать [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
let body = document.body;

console.log('style '+ body.style.backgroundColor);
console.log('getComputedStyle '+ getComputedStyle(body)['background-color']);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.info('смена цвета');

  body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

  console.log('style '+body.style.backgroundColor);
  console.log('getComputedStyle '+getComputedStyle(body)['background-color']);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {background-color: orange;}
```

Comment: или `computedStyleMap` вместо `getComputedStyle`, новая штука, более удобная

Comment: Странно что вы упомянули о CSS стилях так как в контексте данного вопроса очевидно используются инлайн стили, иначе автор вопроса не использовал бы `el.style` для присвоения и получения стилей, к тому же мой ответ отмечен как верный поэтому тем более странно что вы упомянули о CSS стилях. (В ваше оправдание это хорошо что вы делаете такие развёрнутые ответы т.к. пользователи, которые будут искать ответ на такой вопрос смогут решить свою проблему даже если это будут CSS стили)

Comment: @ΝNL993, спасибо за комментарий. Просто по коду автора не совсем ясно что требуется, т.к. в функцию не передаётся никаких параметров, есть только `.style.backgroundColor`, по коду сложилось впечатление, что требуется получить цвет `body`, а не назначить. Тем не менее в моём ответе учитывается и тот и другой вариант. А на галочку не претендую)